# Certificate missing SAN section

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

My certificate request has SAN:

```
» openssl req -in csr/example.com.csr -noout -text
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 0 (0x0)
        Subject: CN=example.com, O=Something, C=XX, ST=YYY, L=Someplace
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:e3:5c:b4:4c:7b:b1:8f:9f:66:0e:0d:de:d1:c6:
                    e0:48:c9:ba:1c:00:e9:22:f9:44:fd:91:53:c3:81:
                    a8:99:7b:8b:48:f6:32:aa:58:cf:ff:47:d6:b6:20:
                    d4:53:a7:6d:03:02:bd:75:dd:ca:aa:81:2d:f1:fd:
                    67:c1:4a:fe:d7:6f:0e:5c:41:13:0f:d8:30:ea:a6:
                    0f:2f:fd:56:43:df:be:5f:68:c5:5f:8a:fd:ad:9c:
                    c4:e6:87:b4:5b:1f:36:a8:b5:d3:aa:98:c7:5f:08:
                    0e:65:42:e6:d0:4d:3d:51:b3:33:af:59:0f:17:2d:
                    7e:99:d0:58:7a:00:85:65:ff:a2:4e:3b:ca:de:ec:
                    fb:bb:c4:53:50:c2:a8:90:b9:09:3d:ee:91:af:24:
                    f4:3e:0f:62:d2:eb:4a:77:a2:72:b8:11:5e:6c:4c:
                    95:99:03:4f:3e:48:dc:e5:95:3c:b6:ce:2f:50:d8:
                    12:8e:98:67:44:3b:a7:2d:46:04:de:96:3e:c8:89:
                    21:1d:e6:ce:ed:2f:24:32:85:ee:4e:35:b3:19:d7:
                    fe:00:4e:e1:a1:1c:3a:9d:ba:72:39:eb:bc:f8:b3:
                    4e:43:07:0a:4c:a2:aa:35:5b:95:88:13:15:0f:bb:
                    a9:77:37:66:0e:3a:05:c2:95:fd:cf:50:f5:bb:bd:
                    4d:07
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        Attributes:
        Requested Extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:example.com, DNS:www.example.com
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         2a:60:b5:f8:1e:aa:72:c1:7d:c8:aa:2f:09:82:71:0f:25:7a:
         1c:2b:b2:87:4c:9e:d3:82:50:b6:da:52:d3:09:a1:70:5a:ea:
         56:94:a8:b9:52:87:cd:35:40:35:51:c9:72:5e:a6:be:8e:e9:
         d2:9f:63:1a:4f:62:a3:2b:83:10:80:8a:6a:a9:de:7f:f6:42:
         b5:b8:a7:d5:8e:dc:33:a5:6a:5a:08:d6:8c:ab:cd:75:74:cd:
         1d:12:ef:72:dd:6c:4d:95:f9:cf:ad:ea:6e:73:e5:cc:4a:e5:
         0a:48:65:20:42:c3:46:0b:6a:1b:3e:49:b1:4e:1d:03:4d:80:
         e0:de:fa:fd:52:96:a5:6d:88:d0:a7:66:d6:fa:0a:ed:89:91:
         31:b3:0c:3a:18:f8:91:0c:1a:ca:21:22:40:af:24:14:e5:9c:
         04:5b:2a:d6:a4:bf:3f:04:00:7d:d1:35:47:e4:c5:58:83:0e:
         87:e2:70:c0:9a:89:cc:89:88:67:df:9d:cb:8d:4e:a4:a2:fa:
         f7:36:4c:44:b2:0a:e1:73:b4:a7:58:b8:5b:16:22:d4:19:b0:
         d5:a2:83:08:4b:d9:22:8e:85:7f:c7:86:8d:97:f8:b1:b6:5b:
         86:b2:c7:a5:09:da:78:4d:c0:39:b5:4e:b1:0d:a2:74:04:95:
         04:92:ed:16
```

But the certificate has lost it:

```
» openssl x509 -in certs/example.com.crt -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: 17807092983826911732 (0xf71f80b9075a91f4)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: O=OOO, L=LLLL, ST=STST, C=CC
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 20 10:46:25 2018 GMT
            Not After : Aug  2 10:46:25 2019 GMT
        Subject: CN=example.com, O=OOO, C=CC, ST=STST, L=LLLL
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:e3:5c:b4:4c:7b:b1:8f:9f:66:0e:0d:de:d1:c6:
                    e0:48:c9:ba:1c:00:e9:22:f9:44:fd:91:53:c3:81:
                    a8:99:7b:8b:48:f6:32:aa:58:cf:ff:47:d6:b6:20:
                    d4:53:a7:6d:03:02:bd:75:dd:ca:aa:81:2d:f1:fd:
                    67:c1:4a:fe:d7:6f:0e:5c:41:13:0f:d8:30:ea:a6:
                    0f:2f:fd:56:43:df:be:5f:68:c5:5f:8a:fd:ad:9c:
                    c4:e6:87:b4:5b:1f:36:a8:b5:d3:aa:98:c7:5f:08:
                    0e:65:42:e6:d0:4d:3d:51:b3:33:af:59:0f:17:2d:
                    7e:99:d0:58:7a:00:85:65:ff:a2:4e:3b:ca:de:ec:
                    fb:bb:c4:53:50:c2:a8:90:b9:09:3d:ee:91:af:24:
                    f4:3e:0f:62:d2:eb:4a:77:a2:72:b8:11:5e:6c:4c:
                    95:99:03:4f:3e:48:dc:e5:95:3c:b6:ce:2f:50:d8:
                    12:8e:98:67:44:3b:a7:2d:46:04:de:96:3e:c8:89:
                    21:1d:e6:ce:ed:2f:24:32:85:ee:4e:35:b3:19:d7:
                    fe:00:4e:e1:a1:1c:3a:9d:ba:72:39:eb:bc:f8:b3:
                    4e:43:07:0a:4c:a2:aa:35:5b:95:88:13:15:0f:bb:
                    a9:77:37:66:0e:3a:05:c2:95:fd:cf:50:f5:bb:bd:
                    4d:07
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         58:fa:f2:83:e1:34:50:f7:f2:04:28:af:0d:e7:27:8d:36:03:
         d3:a9:07:69:ed:5c:3e:2a:ed:e9:2a:58:f8:a3:ef:9b:4e:a6:
         ee:0a:a8:19:84:9d:5a:51:e0:7f:eb:3d:24:be:d9:9e:84:5b:
         4a:6f:57:10:b6:6b:1e:e9:12:91:bd:55:47:20:79:7f:1a:a5:
         83:b6:5c:04:7f:06:3f:f4:97:af:a5:27:7a:81:b7:08:b8:16:
         dd:f1:ab:6d:5a:f8:07:11:f3:97:96:86:08:13:42:b9:de:25:
         38:3e:ee:84:96:93:70:2a:a6:fc:7f:29:25:5d:a8:4c:c7:7c:
         3f:7a:c2:d4:9d:6e:cc:0e:b0:2c:38:dd:4c:d3:91:65:fd:cc:
         f8:ec:4d:9c:d4:88:79:e8:fc:3a:ee:8f:00:dd:9e:95:5c:ca:
         d8:bd:f7:e8:7c:cc:b4:9e:53:6c:60:d8:7a:d2:f2:4f:4a:76:
         3f:0c:33:6f:cf:d0:72:93:39:7e:12:e7:19:f4:e2:77:bf:a0:
         b7:57:22:a9:34:25:51:86:15:26:3a:8c:b2:00:29:d8:5f:98:
         69:f9:b0:36:75:a6:ca:2f:67:dc:5a:11:b2:c3:00:ab:05:6c:
         40:2c:77:d5:0d:53:1b:bb:d6:1f:dd:cd:88:95:26:e1:88:32:
         f7:92:0b:ef
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDMjCCAhoCCQD3H4C5B1qR9DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBQMR0wGwYDVQQKExRE
YW5pZWwgTWV0cm8gU3lzdGVtczEUMBIGA1UEBxMLRHVlc3NlbGRvcmYxDDAKBgNV
BAgTA05SVzELMAkGA1UEBhMCREUwHhcNMTgwMzIwMTA0NjI1WhcNMTkwODAyMTA0
NjI1WjBmMRQwEgYDVQQDDAtleGFtcGxlLmNvbTEdMBsGA1UECgwURGFuaWVsIE1l
dHJvIFN5c3RlbXMxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkRFMQwwCgYDVQQIDANOUlcxFDASBgNVBAcM
C0R1ZXNzZWxkb3JmMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA41y0
THuxj59mDg3e0cbgSMm6HADpIvlE/ZFTw4GomXuLSPYyqljP/0fWtiDUU6dtAwK9
dd3KqoEt8f1nwUr+128OXEETD9gw6qYPL/1WQ9++X2jFX4r9rZzE5oe0Wx82qLXT
qpjHXwgOZULm0E09UbMzr1kPFy1+mdBYegCFZf+iTjvK3uz7u8RTUMKokLkJPe6R
ryT0Pg9i0utKd6JyuBFebEyVmQNPPkjc5ZU8ts4vUNgSjphnRDunLUYE3pY+yIkh
HebO7S8kMoXuTjWzGdf+AE7hoRw6nbpyOeu8+LNOQwcKTKKqNVuViBMVD7updzdm
DjoFwpX9z1D1u71NBwIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQBY+vKD4TRQ9/IE
KK8N5yeNNgPTqQdp7Vw+Ku3pKlj4o++bTqbuCqgZhJ1aUeB/6z0kvtmehFtKb1cQ
tmse6RKRvVVHIHl/GqWDtlwEfwY/9JevpSd6gbcIuBbd8attWvgHEfOXloYIE0K5
3iU4Pu6ElpNwKqb8fyklXahMx3w/esLUnW7MDrAsON1M05Fl/cz47E2c1Ih56Pw6
7o8A3Z6VXMrYvffofMy0nlNsYNh60vJPSnY/DDNvz9Bykzl+EucZ9OJ3v6C3VyKp
NCVRhhUmOoyyACnYX5hp+bA2dabKL2fcWhGywwCrBWxALHfVDVMbu9Yf3c2IlSbh
iDL3kgvv
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

What could be the reason? The `CA_default` of the root CA has:

```
copy_extensions                = copy
```

### EDIT

Adding a copy of my (edited) config (for the CA root cert):

```
#
# OpenSSL configuration file.
#

# Establish working directory.

dir                            = data

[ ca ]
default_ca                     = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
serial                         = $dir/serial
database                       = $dir/certindex.txt
new_certs_dir                  = $dir/certs
certificate                    = $dir/cacert.pem
private_key                    = $dir/private/cakey.pem
default_days                   = 365
default_md                     = md5
preserve                       = no
email_in_dn                    = no
nameopt                        = default_ca
certopt                        = default_ca
policy                         = policy_match

[ policy_match ]
countryName                    = match
stateOrProvinceName            = match
organizationName               = match
organizationalUnitName         = optional
commonName                     = supplied
emailAddress                   = optional

[ req ]
default_bits                   = 1024                   # Size of keys
default_keyfile                = key.pem                # name of generated keys
default_md                     = md5                    # message digest algorithm
string_mask                    = nombstr                # permitted characters
distinguished_name             = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions                 = v3_req

[ req_distinguished_name ]
# Variable name                Prompt string
#-------------------------     ----------------------------------
0.organizationName             = MyOrg
organizationalUnitName         = Organizational Unit Name
emailAddress                   = something@here.net
emailAddress_max               = 40
localityName                   = ThisLocation
stateOrProvinceName            = ThisState
countryName                    = RQ
countryName_min                = 2
countryName_max                = 2
commonName                     = My Certificate Authority
commonName_max                 = 64

# Default values for the above, for consistency and less typing.
# Variable name                Value
#------------------------      ------------------------------
0.organizationName_default     = Organizational Unit Name
localityName_default           = ThisLocation
stateOrProvinceName_default    = ThisState
countryName_default            = RQ

[ v3_ca ]
basicConstraints               = CA:TRUE
subjectKeyIdentifier           = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier         = keyid:always,issuer:always

[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints               = CA:FALSE
subjectKeyIdentifier           = hash
```

### EDIT2

The conf for the CSR:

```
#
# OpenSSL configuration file, for generating CSRs
#

[req]
distinguished_name             = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions                 = v3_req

[ req_distinguished_name ]
# Variable name                Prompt string
#-------------------------     ----------------------------------
0.organizationName             = Some Org
organizationalUnitName         = Some Unit
emailAddress                   = here@there.net
localityName                   = SomeLoc
stateOrProvinceName            = SomeState
countryName                    = RQ
commonName                     = The Common Name

[ v3_req ]

# Extensions to add to a certificate request

basicConstraints               = CA:FALSE
keyUsage                       = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName                 = $ENV::ALTNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently creating a version 1 certificate.  These early certificate don't have extensions, which is why the extensions in your requests aren't being copied.

To resolve this, you need to add the `x509_extensions = <name>` option; where `<name>` is the name of a section that lists extensions to be added to the new certificate. This will force OpenSSL to create version 3 certificates, which is the version that supports extensions. If you don't want to force the CA to add any additional extensions to the new certificates, simply leave this section as empty - but it must exist to create a V3 certificate.

For example:

```
x509_extensions = cert_ext

[cert_ext]

# This is an empty section - the next section starts below
```

It might be safer to add the `basicContstraints` extension to your new certificates with the `basicConstraints = critical,CA:FALSE` option in your section, to ensure that nobody tries to sneak a CA certificate request through.

```
x509_extensions = cert_ext

[cert_ext]

basicConstraints = critical,CA:FALSE

# The next section starts below
```

Comment: To sign the request and generate the site's cert, I use this command: `ALTNAME="$ALTNAME" openssl x509 -req -in csr/$domain.csr -CA data/certs/rootCA.pem -CAkey data/private/rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out data/certs/$domain.crt -days 500 -sha256`. I do not use any config file for signing, so I am not sure how to "force version 3"

Comment: Your answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804820/647991) helped a lot

Comment: You could use the `openssl ca` command instead.

Comment: Yes, but I have no configuration for that ...

Comment: The `[CA_default]` __is__ the configuration for that :-)

Comment: I see. Now that you mention that: is it correct practice to have one config  for the root CA, and another for the CSR / cert generation? Otherwise it seems that I get into trouble with conflicting parameters ...

Comment: The cert generation will be done on the end-entity that requires the certificate.  The certificate signing will be done on the CA.  If both are the same server, it might be wise to use different config files, but not mandatory.  You could investigate the `-extensions` command line option too.